# Java: Find the Depth of a Node not Found in a BST

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, depth

I have a binary search tree that stores in Strings, and I have been able to find the depths or heights of Strings that exist in the BST, but what I'm trying to do is find what the depth would be for a String that is not in the BST.

Here is the algorithm that I'm using currently, which works perfectly to find the depth of a String that already exists in the BST:

```
public int getDepth(String data) {
    return getDepth(root, data, 1);
}

public int getDepth(Node root, String data, int level) {
    if (root == null)
        return 0;

    if (root.getData().getName().equals(data))
        return level;

    int ret = getDepth(root.leftChild, data, level + 1);
    if (ret != 0)
        return ret;

    ret = getDepth(root.rightChild, data, level + 1);
    return ret;

}
```

My BST has the elements that were inserted in this order: "cat", "bird", "dog", "tiger", "elephant", "panda".

So the binary tree should look like this:

```
                                   cat
                                  /   \
                               bird   dog
                                         \
                                        tiger
                                       /     \
                                  elephant  panda
```

When I call the method on "dog" the output is: dog is at depth 2

When I call the method on "hippo" the output is: hippo is at depth 0

But the expected output of "hippo" should be: hippo is at depth 5

Because hippo would be a child of elephant which is already in depth 4.

Then for another case, what if I wanted to find the depth of "cow" that is not in the BST? It would have to be the left child of dog so the depth should be 3, however, I still get 0.

So the question is without using a delete and/or restore method what case(s) do I need or what case(s) do I need to modify in the method above in order to determine the depth of a String not inside the BST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this modified version of your second `getDepth()` method:

```
public int getDepth(Node root, String data) {
    if (root == null || root.getData().getName().equals(data)) {
        // you hit the spot - either you are below a leaf
        // or you matched the node
        // if you were doing insert/replace, you would put the data on this spot
        return 0;
    }

    if (isSmallerThan(data, root.getData().getName())) {
        return 1 + getDepth(root.leftChild, data);
    }
    return 1 + getDepth(root.rightChild, data);
}
```

where `isSmallerThan(String a, String b)` returns `true` if `a` is *smaller* than `b`. This method depends on how you want your strings to be compared.

And you don't need to pass the `level` all along...

Comment: I like it! Thanks for the help! BSTs are new to me, so I'm still trying to figure them out.

Answer (score 2):

you'll need to simulate an `insert` operation which does everything a real insert would do except it doesn't append a new node to the tree and does keep track of the depth.
search for the correct location to insert the new value - start at the root, compare the value to the current node, descend down the tree according to the result of the comparison.
once the correct location is found, don't add the value to the tree, just return the depth.

Comment: Great idea that I have already tried, but I still get the same results because I guess whatever I returned is wrong, and that's where the confusion is coming in.

Comment: @zoltack429 Jan gave a nice implementation example, compare it to your own and see where the difference in logic lies